# What character options allow receiving random visions?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, feats, class, character-templates

I'd like to introduce to my campaign a human NPC that suffers from vague and uncontrollable visions of the future.

Are there classes, feats, magic items, or templates that give such an ability?

Comment: [Possibly of interest.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47097/8610)

Comment: I hope it's okay that I made a significant edit to this so as to reduce it to the core question and so it doesn't look quite so broad, all the while omitting the loaded term *oracle* (*a la Pathfinder*). I think this question can be answered with a very small list — *so* small, in fact, that I don't know if it would have *any* entries.

Comment: That is fine with me. But the list seems to be short indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Spell-touched feat: Omniscient Whispers...

... would be a good start. I would combine it with a custom flaw: Uncontrollable Ability (select one limited use ability, that ability now triggers randomly (percentage chance or the DM may choose when it activates).

However, having suggested this, I cannot recall any pre-existing material which would exactly match this effect.

Comment: Thank you! I did not consider spell-touched feats up to now, but this really has potential.

Comment: You are most welcome.